# How to define min and max with sumifs() in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a problem and looking for a smart solution.

In my excel sheet, I defined the following columns with values:

`CalcSheet`:
[image]

`MasterSheet`:

[image]

I'm working with the following function in Column C of MasterSheet:

```
    =SUMIFS(
        CalcSheet!D:D;
        CalcSheet!A:A; A4;
        CalcSheet!E:E; E4;
        CalcSheet!B:B; "<="&B4;
        CalcSheet!C:C;">"&B4
    )
```

How can I define the case, when an ID don't have a max value? When I let the cell empty, I get the value 0. So that my solution for the moment is to set the Max value to a bigger value then the Volume is. But it isn't a nice solution.

### EDIT:

CalcSheet:

[image]

MasterSheet:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the Max value cell empty, then you can have OR condition like this:

```
= SUMIFS( CalcSheet!D:D; CalcSheet!A:A; A4; CalcSheet!E:E; E4; CalcSheet!B:B; "<="&B4; CalcSheet!C:C;">"&B4 )
+ SUMIFS( CalcSheet!D:D; CalcSheet!A:A; A4; CalcSheet!E:E; E4; CalcSheet!B:B; "<="&B4; CalcSheet!C:C;"" )
```

or with one `SumProduct` formula:

```
= SumProduct( CalcSheet!D:D * ( CalcSheet!A:A = A4 ) * ( CalcSheet!E:E = E4) *
  ( CalcSheet!B:B <= B4 ) * ( ( CalcSheet!C:C > B4 ) + ( CalcSheet!C:C = "" ) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but I'm getting an error when I'm using SumProduct => `a value used in this formula is of the wrong data type`

Comment: hmm that is strange .. does it work with the `SUMIFS` version ? Maybe change the last `CalcSheet!C:C = ""` to `CalcSheet!C:C = 0`

Comment: this doesn't work, too. The first solution works. but it don't want with the sumproduct function.

Comment: I'm testing the formula again and found out, that when 2 IDs don't have a max value then the programme return just for the last ID the procent value. Look above my edited thread.